# jquery Datepicker plugin, rollover --> get date

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datepicker

I have a question about jQuery datepicker.

Datepicker has:   `onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {`    "callback function", which means "on click" I guess, but :

I would like to get date info on rollover event   (.hover, mouseover), and I cannot find it on documentation so I guess no standard way to get it.

Can somebody suggest me a way to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "rollover event"?

Comment: What is this rollover event? is it .mouseover() or .hover()  !!

Comment: let's say hover, But I am okey with "mouseover" as well

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:

```
$("element_selector").mouseover(function(){
    $('datepicker_selector').datepicker("getDate");
});
```

check out the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: I think it will get current date, but not rollover date, maybe I am wrong

Comment: What date are you trying to get.. the one in the datepicker?

Comment: that one, what I am  hovering